# How to Obtain strings/values from bytearrays in postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column called order_ids where the data is in bytearrays. How would I obtain the strings or the values from these bytearrays in postgresql?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hope this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/using-postgresql-8-4-how-to-convert-bytea-to-text-value-in-postgres  can help you.